# Как получить список всех сайтов на одном IP (Reverse IP)

Tags: php

Как на php получить список всех сайтов на одном IP (Reverse IP)? Не используя парсера bing и т.п

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что никак нельзя с точностью узнать все сайты на одном ip.
Есть сервисы, но они показывают только те сайты, которые они спарсили (впрочем как и бинг), т.е. получили ip по имени хоста.

- http://website.informer.com/93.125.99.10
- https://2ip.ru/domain-list-by-ip/

Их базы могут чего-то не включать. Теоретически ведь на один ip можно сколько угодно много повесить хостов.